# setState in React + TypeScript: FormData is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create an upload button using ReactJS with typescript. For now, I just want to do it super simple, and followed this tutorial for "classic" ReactJS: https://www.js-tutorials.com/react-js/learn-react-file-upload-in-5-minute/

Here is my version using with typescript:

```
type UploadProps = {

}

type UploadState = {
    selectedFile: FileList | null
}

class Upload extends Component<UploadProps, UploadState>{
    constructor(props: UploadProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedFile: null
        }
    }

onChangeHandler = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.setState({
        selectedFile: event.currentTarget.files
    })
}

onClickHandler = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('multipartFile', this.state.selectedFile);
    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/upload", formData).then(response => {
        console.log(response.statusText);
    })
}

render() {
    return(
        <div className="Dropzone">
            <input className="FileInput" type="file" accept=".xls, .xlsx" onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
            <img className="Icon" alt="upload" src="cloud_upload-24px.svg" />
            <div className="Upload">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-sucess btn-block" onClick={this.onClickHandler}>Upload</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

}

I get the correct state for the onChangeHandler: `{ "selectedFile": "FileList(undefined) {{…}}" }`

The issue is that I get the error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'FileList | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | Blob'.
```

It seems like the state is not updated.
I tried to create a variable file: any like:

```
onClickHandler = () => {
let file: any = this.state.selectedFile;
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('multipartFile', file, file.name);
axios.post("http://localhost:8080/upload", formData).then(response => {
    console.log(response.statusText);
})
```

}

But obviously, when I upload the file to the server I get the same error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the error said, the argument can be null, then, we should add:

```
if (this.state.file) {
   //code
}
```

Comment: how have you managed the error filelist is not assignable to blob because the if clause only fixes the is possible null exception.